# I need a CSV file with 1 line for saveas

Tags: csv, imacros

I have a file with multiple macros. I am having trouble with on line, the 'SaveAs' line.

The code:

```
'   /\  \     /\__\     /\  \     /\  \     /\  \     /\  \     /\  \  
'  _\:\  \   /::L_L_   /::\  \   /::\  \   /::\  \   /::\  \   /::\  \ 
' /\/::\__\ /:/L:\__\ /::\:\__\ /:/\:\__\ /::\:\__\ /:/\:\__\ /\:\:\__\
' \::/\/__/ \/_/:/  / \/\::/  / \:\ \/__/ \;:::/  / \:\/:/  / \:\:\/__/
'  \:\__\     /:/  /    /:/  /   \:\__\    |:\/__/   \::/  /   \::/  / 
'   \/__/     \/__/     \/__/     \/__/     \|__|     \/__/     \/__/  

'   /\  \     /\  \     /\  \  
'  /::\  \   /::\  \   /::\  \ 
' /:/\:\__\ /\:\:\__\ /::\:\__\
' \:\ \/__/ \:\:\/__/ \:\:\/  /
'  \:\__\    \::/  /   \:\/  / 
'   \/__/     \/__/     \/__/  

VERSION BUILD=8810214 RECORDER=FX
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
TAB T=1
URL GOTO=http://www.nutrivictoria.com/comprar.php?recordID=417-animal-omega-universal-nutrition-30-packs
SET !EXTRACT {{!URLCURRENT}}
SET !VAR1 {{!EXTRACT}}
SET !EXTRACT NULL
'Extraccion del Titulo
TAG POS=1 TYPE=H1 ATTR=ITEMPROP:name&&CLASS:DescripcionProducto1 EXTRACT=TXT
SET !VAR2 {{!EXTRACT}}
SET !EXTRACT NULL
'Extractor de la Descripcion del Articulo
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:TextoComprar EXTRACT=HTM
SET !VAR3 {{!EXTRACT}}
SET !EXTRACT NULL
'Extraccion de la informacion del Articulo
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:InformacionProducto EXTRACT=HTM
TAG POS=2 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:InformacionProducto EXTRACT=HTM
TAG POS=3 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:InformacionProducto EXTRACT=HTM
TAG POS=4 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:InformacionProducto EXTRACT=HTM
SET !VAR4 {{!EXTRACT}}
SET !EXTRACT NULL
'Extraccion del precio
TAG POS=1 TYPE=P ATTR=CLASS:PrecioProductos2 EXTRACT=TXT
SET !VAR5 {{!EXTRACT}}
SET !EXTRACT NULL
'Extracción de la imagen
TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG ATTR=ITEMPROP:im* EXTRACT=HREF
SET !VAR6 {{!EXTRACT}}
SET !EXTRACT NULL

'Anexacion Multiple
ADD !EXTRACT {{!VAR1}}
ADD !EXTRACT {{!VAR2}}
ADD !EXTRACT {{!VAR3}}
ADD !EXTRACT {{!VAR4}}
ADD !EXTRACT {{!VAR5}}
ADD !EXTRACT {{!VAR6}}

'Volcado del contenido
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=D:\ FILE=Articulos.csv
```

Example bad results: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y10za.jpg

How can I get that SaveAs working?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that the newlines (\n characters) are causing the csv reader to put your output on multiple lines.

You can try adding the line below before your SAVEAS command

```
SET !EXTRACT EVAL("var extr2=\"{{!EXTRACT}}\"; extr2.replace(/\n/g,''); ")

'Volcado del contenido
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=D:\ FILE=Articulos.csv
```